# ASP.NET - How it different to remove debug=true and making debug=false in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web-deployment

Once deploying ASP.NET application, is there any difference between
changing debug=false and remove the entire content of debug=true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.85).aspx

> *debug*
>
> Optional Boolean attribute. Specifies whether to compile debug
>   binaries rather than retail binaries. The default is False.

So no difference at all.